# Return 4th business day (excluding public holidays) from a given date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, function, t-sql

The idea here is that a fee will be charged from the fourth day after the invoice date.

The following code works but I'm just wondering if there is a more efficient way to achieve this as I could only think of using a cursor to get my fourth day.
It will be eventually become a function.
I will pass a date (but using getdate() as example here) and return the 4th business day.
NB: A business day excludes Saturday and Sunday and public holidays. I have a table of public holidays.

```
DECLARE @test_date AS DATETIME, @test_day_number as int

DECLARE billdate CURSOR FOR 
WITH DateSequence AS (
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(DAY, num, GETDATE()) AS target_date,
        DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, num, GETDATE())) AS day_of_week
    FROM (
        VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8)
    ) AS nums(num)
)
    SELECT 
        ds.target_date AS dates_after_target,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ds.target_date) AS day_number
    FROM
        DateSequence ds
    WHERE
        ds.day_of_week NOT IN (1, 7)  -- Exclude Sunday (1) and Saturday (7)
        AND ds.target_date NOT IN (SELECT hdate FROM holidays) -- exclude holiday dates
    ORDER BY
        ds.target_date
OPEN billdate
FETCH NEXT FROM billdate INTO @test_date, @test_day_number
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
begin 
    if @test_day_number=4 
        break 
    else 
        FETCH NEXT FROM billdate INTO @test_date, @test_day_number
end 

close billdate
deallocate billdate
print @test_date
```

it works as expected but I feel using a cursor is bad?

Comment: A cursor is not required, you need a Calendar table.

Comment: You can also use DATEPART(weekday.... a bit of logic based on the start day could work here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I would say is get yourself a [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/), they are really useful and are pretty much the first thing I add to any new database I build. Then for all invoices your query would be as simple as:

```
WITH WorkingDays AS
(   SELECT c.Date, RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c.Date) 
    FROM dbo.Calendar AS c
    WHERE c.IsWorkingDay = 1
)
SELECT  i.InvoiceID, i.InvoiceDate, wd2.Date
FROM    dbo.Invoice AS i
        INNER JOIN WorkingDays AS wd1
            ON wd1.Date = i.InvoiceDate
        INNER JOIN WorkingDays AS wd2
            ON wd2.RowNumber = wd1.RowNumber + 4;
```

This may not match your schema at all, but hopefully gives enough of an idea to get the gist of this.

To answer your question though you're right, it definitely doesn't need a cursor, but your going to need more than 7 days in your sequence, because various holidays can it requires more than 7 calendar days to make up 4 working days (e.g. in the UK 4 working days after 22nd December is 2nd January which is 11 calendar days later). If you just want the day 4 working days ahead of now, you can simply do:

```
WITH DateSequence AS (
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY n1.n), CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())) AS target_date
    FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS n1(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS n2(n)
)
SELECT  ds.target_date
FROM    DateSequence AS ds
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Holidays AS h WHERE h.Date = ds.Target_date)
AND     (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, ds.target_date) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7 NOT IN (0, 1)
ORDER BY ds.target_date
OFFSET 3 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```

This simply gets the next 100 days after today, then excludes weekends and dates from your holiday table, then uses `OFFSET/FETCH` to get the 4 row.

N.B. I've swapped your weekday logic out for `(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, ds.target_date) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7 NOT IN (1, 2)`. If you simply use `DATEPART(WEEKDAY, <date>)` You're susceptible to issues arising if `DATEFIRST` isn't what you expect. So if `DATEFIRST` was 3, this would exclude Tuesday and Wednesday rather than Saturday and Sunday. [example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GN6l1yY6)

As I say though, this is all much easier with a calendar table:

```
SELECT  c.Date
FROM    dbo.Calendar AS c
WHERE   c.Date > GETDATE()
AND     c.IsWorkingDay = 1
ORDER BY c.Date 
OFFSET 3 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Comment: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`. Your expression (`(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, ds.target_date) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7`) is zero-based so the weekend would be `( 0, 1 )`, not `( 1, 2 )`.

Comment: @HABO Yep, copied some code without thinking there. I've updated the answer

Comment: oh wow - a calendar table! what a great idea, I'm totally doing that. I also hadn't considered the public holiday shifting to a Monday if its falls on the weekend. Thank you so much everyone for all your tips.

Comment: Of course (just to add to my Friday afternoon) in Mexico: When a statutory holiday falls on a Sunday, Monday is considered a statutory holiday; if a statutory holiday falls on Saturday, Friday will be considered a statutory holiday. :-)

Comment: The Calendar table can always be extended so that the "IsWorkingDay" flag is actually calculated based on child tables, one such example is [in this article](https://sonra.io/snowflake/date-dimension-with-global-holiday-calendar/). I'd personally build this slightly differently but it shows the gist. You could then have a table valued function that returned a calender based on a country code with their particular working days flagged, e.g. `SELECT * FROM dbo.CountryCalendar('MX')` to get holidays specific to Mexico.

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach, not better than the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76928977/return-4th-business-day-excluding-public-holidays-from-a-given-date/76929179#76929179) but different:

```
CREATE Function BusinessDay(@day date, @wd smallint = 4)
returns date as
begin
    if @wd = 0
        while (@@DATEFIRST + datePart(dw, @day))%7 in (0,1)
           or exists (select 1 from Holidays where HDate = @day)
              set @day = dateAdd(dd, -1, @day)
    else
        while @wd <> 0
        begin
            set @day = dateAdd(dd, sign(@wd), @day)
            set @wd -= case when (@@DATEFIRST + datePart(dw, @day))%7 in (0,1)
                        or exists (select 1 from Holidays where HDate = @day)
                            then 0 else sign(@wd)
                       end
        end
    return @day
end
```

You could ask for `dbo.BusinessDay(getDate(), DEFAULT)` to get the 4th working day after today or `dbo.BusinessDay(getDate(), -4)` for the 4th working day before today.